# Group contiguous siblings of a type

Tags: xslt

Given siblings, some of which are `<row>` elements and some not, like this,

```
<h />
<row id='v' />
<a />
<b />
<row id='w' />
<d />
<row id='x' />
<row id='y' />
<f />
<r />
<row id='z' />
```

using xslt 1.0, I need to process them in order but to group the non-row ones together as I go, like this,

```
<notRow>
    <h />
</notRow>
<row id='v' />
<notRow>
    <a />
    <b />
</notRow>
<row id='w' />
<notRow>
    <d />
<row id='x' />
<row id='y' />
<notRow>
    <f />
    <r />
</notRow>
<row id='z' />
```

The first and last may or may not be `<row>` elements.

How?

Comment: JPM, You may be interested to see a transformation that is complete, shorter, doesn't use any `xsl:call-template`, any named templates, any `xsl:if` and any `xsl:for-each`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It can be as short and simple as this (no need of calling templates several times, `xsl:for-each`, `xsl:if`). Here is the complete transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:key name="kFollowing" match="*/*[not(self::row)]"
          use="concat(generate-id(..), '+',
                      generate-id(preceding-sibling::row[1])
                     )"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template priority="2" match=
  "*/*[not(self::row)
   and
     (preceding-sibling::*[1][self::row]
    or not(preceding-sibling::*)
     )]">
  <notRow>
    <xsl:copy-of select=
    "key('kFollowing', concat(generate-id(..), '+',
                               generate-id(preceding-sibling::row[1])
                              ))"/>
  </notRow>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*/*[not(self::row)]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML** (wrapped into a single top element to make it well-formed):

```
<t>
    <h />
    <row id='v' />
    <a />
    <b />
    <row id='w' />
    <d />
    <row id='x' />
    <row id='y' />
    <f />
    <r />
    <row id='z' />
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<t>
   <notRow>
      <h/>
   </notRow>
   <row id="v"/>
   <notRow>
      <a/>
      <b/>
   </notRow>
   <row id="w"/>
   <notRow>
      <d/>
   </notRow>
   <row id="x"/>
   <row id="y"/>
   <notRow>
      <f/>
      <r/>
   </notRow>
   <row id="z"/>
</t>
```

**Update**:

The OP has expressed an additional requirement that nodes need be processed by matching templates -- not just copied.

**This requires only minimal change**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:key name="kFollowing" match="*/*[not(self::row)]"
          use="concat(generate-id(..), '+',
                      generate-id(preceding-sibling::row[1])
                     )"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template priority="2" match=
  "*/*[not(self::row)
   and
     (preceding-sibling::*[1][self::row]
    or not(preceding-sibling::*)
     )]">
  <notRow>
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="group" select=
    "key('kFollowing', concat(generate-id(..), '+',
                               generate-id(preceding-sibling::row[1])
                              ))"/>
  </notRow>
 </xsl:template>
 <!-- This template can be replaced with whatever processing needed -->
 <xsl:template match="*" mode="group">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="*/*[not(self::row)]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The template that operates in mode "group" should be substituted with template(s) that implement the exact wanted processing. In this case it copies the matched element -- but in the real application any wanted processing would go here.

Comment: That doesn't look right to me, you've got the second (and presumably subsequent) element in each `notRow` block repeated after the block. I guess you need an appropriate no-op template to block these.

Comment: Very nice. Very clean. I edited it to simplify it even a little bit more.

Comment: By the way, is [self::row] the same as, but better than, [name()='row']?

Comment: @JPM, Not exactly the same, and better. One can have [name()='row'] for any kind of nodes -- elements, attributes, PIs, and even namespaces. On the other side, self::row applies only to elements. self::row is more efficient than name()=row.

Comment: Thanks. And forget that edit I suggested. It worked only as an artifact of the example.

Comment: Oh-oh. I oversimplified the Q. In the real app, I want to apply templates to each row and non-row, not just copy it. I thought the change would be trivial but it's not. Ian's was easy to get working. Now I don't see how to get this one working. Grrr.

Comment: Right. And when there is no "mode" the regular templates will match. Got it. Thanks, Dimitre.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do a trick with a key to group each non-row element by its preceding row (if there is one), or its parent element if not:

```
<xsl:key name="elementsFollowingRow"
  match="*[not(self::row)]"
  use="generate-id( (.. | preceding-sibling::row )[last()])" />
```

and define a named template to put in a notRow if the current element has any associated elements according to the key

```
<xsl:template name="addNotRow">
  <xsl:if test="key('elementsFollowingRow', generate-id())">
    <notRow>
      <xsl:copy-of select="key('elementsFollowingRow', generate-id())" />
    </notRow>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Then in the template where you're matching the parent element (the one that contains all these `row` and non-`row` elements you can do

```
<xsl:call-template name="addNotRow" />
<xsl:for-each select="row">
  <xsl:copy-of select="." />
  <xsl:call-template name="addNotRow" />
</xsl:for-each>
```

The first `call-template` outside the for-each will deal with any `notRow` that is required before the first `row`, and the call inside the for-each will put in any `notRow` required after the row in question.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't pretty, but it works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="t">

        <xsl:if test="row[1]/preceding-sibling::*">
            <notRow>
                <xsl:for-each select="row[1]/preceding-sibling::*" >
                    <xsl:copy />
                </xsl:for-each>
            </notRow>
        </xsl:if>

        <xsl:for-each select="row">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            <xsl:if test="following-sibling::row[1]/preceding-sibling::*[generate-id(preceding-sibling::row[1])=generate-id(current())]">
                <notRow>
                    <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::row[1]/preceding-sibling::*[generate-id(preceding-sibling::row[1])=generate-id(current())]">
                        <xsl:copy />
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </notRow>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>

        <xsl:if test="row[last()]/following-sibling::*">
            <notRow>
                <xsl:for-each select="row[last()]/following-sibling::*" >
                    <xsl:copy />
                </xsl:for-each>
            </notRow>
        </xsl:if>

    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

On this XML source

```
<t>
    <h />
    <i />
    <row id='v' />
    <a />
    <b />
    <row id='w' />
    <d />
    <row id='x' />
    <row id='y' />
    <f />
    <r />
    <row id='z' />
    <i />
</t>
```

it returns the correct result:

```
<notRow>
   <h/>
   <i/>
</notRow>
<row id="v"/>
<notRow>
   <a/>
   <b/>
</notRow>
<row id="w"/>
<notRow>
   <d/>
</notRow>
<row id="x"/>
<row id="y"/>
<notRow>
   <f/>
   <r/>
</notRow>
<row id="z"/>
<notRow>
   <i/>
</notRow>
```

but it does seem there should be something simpler.